# how to invoke controller in partial in Angular Js directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have created a directive for Tab, its working fine for static controller but when add add controller to any one of the template it doesn't show anything.

my Tab directive is here

```
angular.module('nsTab', [])
    .directive('nsTabset',  function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tabs: '=tabs'
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
              $scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[0].url;

        },
        controller: function($scope, $element){

            $scope.activateTab = function(tab){

                $scope.currentTab  = tab.url;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'modules/common/views/tabset.html'
    };
});
```

local scope

```
$scope.tabs = [
    {name: 'Headends', url: 'modules/lineup/views/ShowSystem/head.html', isActive: true},
    {name: 'Contacts', url: 'modules/lineup/views/ShowSystem/contacts.html'}
]
```

directive in html

```
<ns-tabset tabs="tabs"></ns-tabset>
```

content of head.html

```
<div ng-controller="HeadCtrl">{{value}}</div>
```

SystemHeadendCtrl.js

```
angular.module('myMod').controller('HeadCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.headendList = function(){
        $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                         {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                         {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                         {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                         {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
        $scope.value= 10;
        $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
    }
});
```

well its not showing anything in head.html when that tab is active.

Comment: I don't see the `headendList` function being called anywhere. If you don't call it, the `value` property will never be added to the `scope`. Try adding `$scope.headendList();` at the end of the `HeadCtrl`.

Comment: its not working w/o it too

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or a jsfiddle? Also, post the `tabset.html` content.

Comment: its working now, the problem was in the code only, i am sharing the link to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the code only, i am sharing the code of the tab control

http://plnkr.co/edit/SAeRZDp1vg7xxmCdG6Vv

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nsTab']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.tabs = [
                {name: 'Head', url: 'head.html', isActive: true},
                {name: 'Tail', url: 'tail.html'},

            ]

});


angular.module('nsTab', [])
    .directive('nsTabset',  function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
              $scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[0].url;

        },
        controller: function($scope, $element){

            $scope.activateTab = function(tab){

                $scope.currentTab  = tab.url;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'tabset.html'
    };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.test = 'testing';
});
```